# Txt file python unique values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, text-files, unique

So I have a txt file with many lines that look like this:

```
2107|Business|2117|Art|2137|Art|2145|English
```

Essentially it is a random students major and an encoded semester and year that they declared it before it.  What I want to be able to do is read in the semester each unique major was declared initially.  From the line above I would need:

```
2107:Business

2117: Art

2145: English
```

I was attempting to do this with Pandas in Python but really can't get anything to work. 
Any help appreciated?

EDIT:
Should have clarified.  I don't want the code to read in the second instance of Art.  Only the first declaration and semester before for each major.

Comment: What is the type of the end result? Just strings?

Comment: Strings works fine. What I want as an end result would be a pivot table with the encrypted student i.d as a pivot, next column would be 3 rows showing the term ('2107','2117','2145') and a final column with the corresponding majors on each row for each term.

Comment: String is probably not the best bet then. I think you'd want a tuple. That way the data is more easily accessible. Blotosmetek's answer shouldn't be too difficult to adjust to do that though, and if strings works for you then you're golden.

Comment: can you post a part of text file and desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Python's CSV library to help with splitting each of the rows into a list of cells. You can then make use of Python's [`grouper()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html?highlight=pairwise#recipes) recipe which is used to take `n` items at a time out of a list:

```
import csv
import itertools

def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return itertools.izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)

seen = set()

with open('input3.txt', 'rb') as f_input:
    for row in csv.reader(f_input, delimiter='|'):
        for k, v in grouper(row, 2):
            if v not in seen:
                print "{}: {}".format(k, v)
                seen.add(v)
```

So for your example file line, this would give you:

```
2107: Business
2117: Art
2145: English
```

Comment: This looks good but is there a way to only read the first instance of Art?  So the final output would be     2107:Business, 2117:Art, 2145:English.

Comment: You could add each subject into a set and test if it is in the set before printing. I have updated the script accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `l` contains a line "like this":

```
a = l.split('|')
for t in zip(a[0::2], a[1::2]):
    print("{}: {}".format(*t))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module to load the file. For example:

```
import csv
    with open('file.txt', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='|')
    for row in reader:
        print row
```

Now you have a list `row` with everything in the file. `row[n]` for all even values of n is a year/semester and for all odd values of n is a major.